# How save selected option in django template?

Tags: html, django

After submitting the form, I can't save selected choice. 
Please help.

```
<select id="category" class="form-control" name="category">
  {% for option in categories %}
    <option value="{{option.name}}" {% if option.name == 'I don't know what's dynamic value write here(or how get value of POST-parameter' %}selected{% endif %}>
      {{ option.name }}
    </option>
  {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

A correct way to do this will always be with [django forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/)

But if you want to do it with if conditions in template, you will have to pass the currently selected option from views in context, maybe with variable `category` and in templates you can do:

```
<select id="category" class="form-control" name="category">
  {% for option in categories %}
    <option value="{{option.name}}" {% if category == option.name %}selected{% endif %}>
      {{ option.name }}
    </option>
  {% endfor %}
</select>
```